# toggle slide from left to right with smooth movement on click of a show/hide button

Tags: jquery, slide, slidetoggle, css

I have a table with 4 columns and 10 rows having the 4th column hidden by default. 
There is a show/hide image button in the 1st row.

What I need is, when I click on the show/hide image button:

1. the 4th column to appear as if sliding in from left to right
2. a modal overlay div to appear (like lightbox,shadowbox etc.) that will have a close button
3. when I close the modal window and then click on of the show/hide image button again, the 4th column should slide out to left.

The code that I have written is working for me, but it does not slide in from 3rd column towards right and slide back on click again. Also the modal overlay is not working when I click the show/hide button.
Need some help on this to fix.

This is my code:

```
.subtn{
display:inline-block;
background:url("images/next_right.png") right 0px no-repeat;
width:16px;
height:16px;
}
.subtn.expanded{
background:url("images/previous_left.png") right 0px no-repeat;
width:16px;
height:16px;
}




$(document).ready(function(){
  var $content = $("td:nth-child(4)").hide();
  $(".subtn").on("click", function(e){
    $(this).toggleClass("expanded");
    $content.slideToggle();
  });
});



<table>
<tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="right"><a href="#" rel="lightbox" class="subtn"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>sam</td>
        <td>europe</td>
        <td style="display:none;">new</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>john</td>
        <td>europe</td>
        <td style="display:none;">new</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>bob</td>
        <td>africa</td>
        <td style="display:none;">new</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/pEKvq/4/)

Comment: Please simulate the same on Jsfiddle :)

Comment: What you mentioned in the question does not look like what' s in the fiddle. Look it up again

Comment: I have updated the fiddle link. Please check it now. In the first row of the table when I click (the images are not uploaded but its clickable) then the 4th row is showing up but the modal window is not appearing and the 4th window is not sliding to right. Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing about your modal in a code you provided. So I skip this part. As of your 4th column toggle, the trouble is in two points:

1. Animations works good with a block-elements. `TD` is not block by default. So I changed it in your css rules to `display: block`;
2. `slideToggle` is only slide down. For slide from left to right and back you should to use `toggle` with appropriate options;

In jsFiddle you provided there was no a button that should run toggle process. I added it. Anthing works here:
http://jsfiddle.net/pEKvq/7/

Comment: @guyan Feel free to accept and vote up my answer to make it helpfully for others ;)